# How to get float numbers as parameter of \newcommand

Tags: macros, conditionals, calculations, floating-point

I have defined a `\newcommand` function like into this code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pbox,calc}

\newcounter{pointsExo}
\setcounter{pointsExo}{4}
\newcounter{pointsSousTotal}
\setcounter{pointsSousTotal}{0}

\newcounter{souspointsExo}
\newcommand{\sousPoints}[1]{
    \setcounter{souspointsExo}{#1}
    \setcounter{pointsSousTotal}{\value{pointsSousTotal} + #1}
    {\scriptsize{(#1~\ifthenelse{#1<2}{point}{points}}/\arabic{pointsExo})}
}

\newcommand{\subexo}[2]{
    #1\hfill\sousPoints{#2}% Points
    \medskip
}
\begin{document}
\subexo{Anything}{2}

\subexo{Something}{0.5}
\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to call the command with both **real** or **integer** numbers:

```
\subexo{Anything}{2}
```

or

```
\subexo{Something}{0.5}
```

But I have errors like this with my current code:

```
! Package calc Error: `.' invalid at this point.
```

What should I modify into my `\newcommand` definition to do this ?

Comment: As far as I know, counters can assume only integer values. Please take a look on the `calculator` package

Comment: You might want to take a look at class `exam` or package `exsheets`. Looks like you are trying to achieve some kind of exam paper.

Comment: There's some inconsistency in your question: the `\sousPoints ` command is defined as having only one argument, and you use it with two: `\sousPoints{Anything}{2}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B, yes, I will give a look at these packages. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counters can only contain integer numbers. If you want to deal with real numbers you have to play with lengths.

The following MWE uses lengths instead of counters (the internal macro `\strip@pt` is used to strip `pt` when printing the length):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pbox,calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\strippt}[1]{\strip@pt#1}
\makeatother

\newlength{\pointsExo}
\setlength{\pointsExo}{4pt}
\newlength{\pointsSousTotal}
\setlength{\pointsSousTotal}{0pt}

\newlength{\souspointsExo}
\newcommand{\sousPoints}[1]{
    \setlength{\souspointsExo}{#1pt}
    \setlength{\pointsSousTotal}{\pointsSousTotal + #1pt}
    {\scriptsize{(#1~\ifdim#1pt=1pt point\else points\fi/\strippt\pointsExo)}}
}

\newcommand{\subexo}[2]{
    #1\hfill\sousPoints{#2}% Points
    \medskip
}
\begin{document}
\subexo{Anything}{2}

\subexo{Something}{0.5}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! one more question: does all length need to be prefixed with \ ? Should I add a \ to all my counters ?

Comment: @lauhub Yes, lengths are like commands and need a ``\`` before.